# Angular multiselectDropdown giving error element.multiselect is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi am using multiselect directive in angular js .When i redirect to the page via angular rout , it gives me "element.multiselect is not a function" . If i refresh the page manulally it works properly. anyone nknows how to slove it.

```
app.directive('multiselectDropdown', [function() {
return function(scope, element, attributes) {

    element = $(element[0]); // Get the element as a jQuery element
    // Below setup the dropdown:
    element.multiselect({
        buttonClass : 'btn btn-small',
        buttonWidth : '200px',
        buttonContainer : '<div class="btn-group" />',
        maxHeight : 200,
        enableFiltering : true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        buttonText : function(options) {
            if (options.length == 0) {
                return element.data()['placeholder'] + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
            } else if (options.length > 1) {
                return _.first(options).text 
                + ' + ' + (options.length - 1)
                + ' more selected <b class="caret"></b>';
            } else {
                return _.first(options).text
                + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
            }
        },
        // Replicate the native functionality on the elements so
        // that angular can handle the changes for us.
        onChange: function (optionElement, checked) {
            optionElement.prop('selected'), false;
            if (checked) {
                optionElement.prop('selected', true);
            }
            element.change();
        }

    });
    // Watch for any changes to the length of our select element
    scope.$watch(function () {
        return element[0].length;
    }, function () {
        element.multiselect('rebuild');
    });

    // Watch for any changes from outside the directive and refresh
    scope.$watch(attributes.ngModel, function () {
        element.multiselect('refresh');
    });

    // Below maybe some additional setup
};
```

}]);

```
//my html code



<select name ='escalation_rule_ids' class="multiselect" data-placeholder="Select Escalation" 
                                    ng-model="formData.escalation_rule_ids" ng-options="item.id as item.rule_name for item in escalation_list"
                                    multiple="multiple" multiselect-cdropdown
                                    >
                                 </select>
```

Comment: Are you dynamically including the `multiselect` js file in your page?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overwriting the angular element into something else. I would switch it to this:

```
app.directive('multiselectDropdown', [function() {
return function(scope, element, attributes) {

    var jqueryElement = $(element[0]); // Get the element as a jQuery element
    // Below setup the dropdown:
    jqueryElement.multiselect({
        buttonClass : 'btn btn-small',
        buttonWidth : '200px',
        buttonContainer : '<div class="btn-group" />',
        maxHeight : 200,
        enableFiltering : true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        buttonText : function(options) {
            if (options.length == 0) {
                return jqueryElement.data()['placeholder'] + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
            } else if (options.length > 1) {
                return _.first(options).text 
                + ' + ' + (options.length - 1)
                + ' more selected <b class="caret"></b>';
            } else {
                return _.first(options).text
                + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
            }
        },
        // Replicate the native functionality on the elements so
        // that angular can handle the changes for us.
        onChange: function (optionElement, checked) {
            optionElement.prop('selected'), false;
            if (checked) {
                optionElement.prop('selected', true);
            }
            jqueryElement.change();
        }

    });
    // Watch for any changes to the length of our select element
    scope.$watch(function () {
        return element[0].length;
    }, function () {
        jqueryElement.multiselect('rebuild');
    });

    // Watch for any changes from outside the directive and refresh
    scope.$watch(attributes.ngModel, function () {
        jqueryElement.multiselect('refresh');
    });

    // Below maybe some additional setup
};
```